# Redirecting domain names to the same domain?

Tags: redirect, apache2

I want to redirect the following domain names :haloservers.net,haloservers.nl and servers.xgclan.com to the domain name www.haloservers.us
I tried putting the code below in the htaccesses file but this didn't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.?)haloservers.net$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.haloservers.us/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.?)haloservers.nl$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.haloservers.us/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(servers\.)xgclan.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.haloservers.us/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code fixed the problem.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)haloservers(.nl|.net)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.haloservers.us/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?haloservers(.nl|.net) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ http://haloservers.us/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I got my solution from col-dejong @ http://gathering.tweakers.net/forum/list_messages/1497390/last

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?haloservers\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ http://haloservers.us/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried it like but it didn't work, it would just send me to www.xgclan.com
Even when the htaccesses file in that folder was set to do the above.

I also tried the following, but without succes:
RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?haloservers\.net [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ haloservers.us/$1 [R=301,L] RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?haloservers\.nl [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ haloservers.us/$1 [R=301,L] RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(servers\.)?xgclan\.com [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ haloservers.us/$1 [R=301,L]