# Is it possible to have the same DOMAIN NAME for two different webpages? If yes, how can it be achieved?

Tags: javascript, html, apache, dns

If someone tries to access to the website (example.com), it should lead to either one of the websites. I want to keep my old website and also the domain name, but I have the new website and I want to have the same domain name as the old website, but both are in function.
I tried with subdomain but it is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: What would be the difference for others accessing these sites? You need something to differentiate accessing the sites.

Comment: You want `example.com` to show new site and `example.com/old` to show old site?

Comment: no, I want to have same (access point) domain name which is www.example.net for both websites (old and new).  for example old website has domain name www.example.net and the new has www.example.org, and now I want to have  just www.example.net for both of them. :)

Comment: I am new to this, and Im trying to figure out how to do it...
Maybe this is a solution, but like I said I am new to this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000637/redirecting-domain-names-to-the-same-domain

Answer (score 0):

If subdomain isn't something you wanted, you can achieve it by putting the old website/webpage into a directory (or "folder").

For example, you can put your old website/webpage into a folder called "old" on your new website. So the URL for the old website/webpage will be

> example.com/old

By doing so, you can have same domain and two different webpage. If it isn't something you wanted, I don't think there are other way. Hope it helps. **=)**